# How to use getopts in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, getopts

I am new to bash scripting and I am trying to write a script with getopts so that when `script.sh -sp` is is invoked the URL and column and row count is printed out. And when `script.sh -r` option is invoked only the file type is printed.

**Script :**

```
#!/bin/bash

#define the URL 
URL='https://github.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/tree/master/data_raw'
#define file name
filename=$(basename "$URL")
#dowload the file
wget -q "${URL}"

while getopts ":sp:r" o; do
   case $o in
   
   sp ) echo URL: $URL #print the URL address
       awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}END{print "COLUMN NO: "NF " ROWS NO: "NR}' $filename #print the column count and row count
   r ) file $filename #print the file type 
       exit 1
        
   esac
done
```

Can anyone help me understand how to use getopts correctly?

Comment: note that `getopt` and `getopts` are different tools. You wrote `getopt` in the text but tagged the question with `getopts`. But you're also using `getopts` in the code, so I guess that's what you actually want.

Comment: in any case, neither of them supports multi-character options. `-sp` would be the two options `-s` and `-p`. (or `-s` with the option-argument `p`, if `-s` took an opt-arg.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getopts` only supports single-character option names, and supports clustering: `-sp` is equivalent to passing `-s` and `-p` separately if `-s` doesn't take an argument, and it's the option `-s` with the argument `p` if `-s` takes an argument. This is the normal convention on Unix-like systems: after a single dash `-`, each character is a separate option (until an option that takes an argument); after a double dash `--`, everything (up to `=`) is the option name.

So `getopts ":sp:r" o` declares three options: `-s` and `-r` with no argument, and `-p` with an argument. You seem to only want two options and neither expects an argument, so the correct specification would be `sr`, and the usage would be `script.sh` `script.sh -s` or `script.sh -r` or `script.sh -rs` or `script.sh -r -s` etc.

```
while getopts sr o; do
  case $o in
    s)
      echo "URL: $URL" #print the URL address
      awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}END{print "COLUMN NO: "NF " ROWS NO: "NR}' -- "$filename" #print the column count and row count
      ;;
    r) file -- "$filename";; #print the file type
    \?) exit 3;; #invalid option
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1)) # remove options, keep non-option arguments
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  echo >&2 "$0: unexpected argument: $1"
  exit 3
fi
```

The leading `:` says not to report unknown options to the user. Unknown options still cause `$o` to be `?`. If you do that, you should print a message when `$o` is `?`. And either way you should exit with a failure status if an option is unknown.

Other errors I fixed:

- Added missing `;;` in the `case` syntax.
- Removed `exit 1` in a success case.
- Added [missing double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).
- Added missing `--` in front of command arguments that might start with `-`.
- Added error handling.

Note that it's spelled `getopts`, not `getopt`. There is a separate utility called `getopt` which has the same purpose but works differently and is rather harder to use. It doesn't support multiple-character options introduced by a single dash either, but it does support long options introduced by double dash.