# how to exit immediately with getopts option in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

what I tried.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# set -e

echo hello
while getopts sr o; do
  case $o in
    s)
        echo "no" 
        yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
        die() { yell "$*"; exit 111; }
        try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }
        
      ;;
    r) 
        echo "yes"
        yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
        die() { yell "$*"; exit 111; }
        try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }
        ;;
    \?) exit 3;; #invalid option
  esac
done

echo after_case
```

What I am trying to do:
in terminal, the following 2 command:
`bash /home/jian/Desktop/pgdev/test1.sh -s`
`bash /home/jian/Desktop/pgdev/test1.sh -r`
do not print out `aftercase`.

references: [How to use getopts in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684717/how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378274/in-a-bash-script-how-can-i-exit-the-entire-script-if-a-certain-condition-occurs

Comment: As written the program loops over the provided options. A case statement processes each option, doing an echo and defining 3 functions. When there are no more options then loop exists and then the program prints out "after_case". To avoid getting to the after_case you could call `exit` in the case statement. However if you do so there is no point in defining the functions as the definitions will be lost when the shell exits. Normally you would put the main part of your script where it says after_case, using the yell die try statements. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why do you expect the behaviour you describe? There is nothing that actually stop the script when only given `r` and/or `s` as options.

Comment: what I am trying to do: based on getopt, stop executing in the middle of a script file. @icarus

Comment: Why are you defining the `yell`/`die`/`try` functions multiple times? They don't seem to change, so just put the once at the top of the script. Or do you think that defining the `try` function like `try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }` actually also invokes it?

Comment: @muru because I don't understand. So I give It a try. I thought yell/die/try a least one will exit the script.

Comment: Defining a function doesn't call it. You need to actually use `try` or `die` as a command.

Comment: @muru. not sure what you mean. basically. sometimes when I do development, I need bash script to stop in the middle of a script file. Executing the whole script would take long. sometimes I only want part a of a bash file.

Comment: `func() { ... }` is a function definition, it creates the function. It doesn't run it. The command to exit the script is `exit`, the same you have there in the last branch of the `case`.

Comment: yes! @ilkkachu that's the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Your yell(), die() and try() function can be written at the top of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
usage() {
    echo "usage: <command> options:<s|r|o>"
    echo "-s s_value -r r_value -o o_value"
}
yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
die() { yell "$*"; exit 111; }
try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }
no_args="true"
while getopts s:r:o: flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
    s) yell
       die
       try
          ;;
    r) resource=${OPTARG} ;;
    o) other=${OPTARG} ;;
    *)
        usage
        exit
        ;;
    esac
    no_args="false"
done
[[ "$no_args" == "true" ]] && {
    usage
    exit 1
}
## other things to do
```

Comment: Why the `yell`, `die` and `try` calls in `s)`? The last one doesn't even do anything

Comment: you can do something like `s) some=${OPTARG} ;;` and invoke this in another line. the original question was like that, thats why i mentioned it

Comment: original question was just to exit. If you look at how the functions are defined, you'll note that `yell` doesn't do anything useful much without arguments, and `die` exits the script so the `try` after it doesn't get to do anything